# Verify if the contents in Zip folder are present in the XML metadata with no discrepancy

Tags: c#, xml

I am working on a program that should check the contents of a Zip folder by running the numbers against the XML metadata file which would be transferred within the Zip folder itself. The other files present in the Zip folder are **AFP** format.
Foreach AFP contained in the zip folder the XML metadata tag should have an element defined, for eg:

```
<file>
  <name>AFP FILE NAME X</name>
  <code>AFP FILE CODE Y</code>
  <pagecount>AFP PAGE COUNT Z</pagecount>
</file>
<file>
  <name>AFP FILE NAME A</name>
  <code>AFP FILE CODE B</code>
  <pagecount>AFP PAGE COUNT C</pagecount>
</file>
.
.
.
```

The program should verify the AFP contents against their respective file tags. I am using an internal library to load and read the file contents of AFP.
What I am not able to do is read the xml and later compare them with their respective AFP matter and report any issue seen.

Comment: You need to check LINQ to XML API. It has `XDocument` data type to handle XML files.

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky, thank you for the reply, I have started using XDocument, what I am not able to implement is the logic to compare the parsed elements with AFP content.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq and put results in a dictionary that you can use for comparison

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<string, List<File>> dict = doc.Descendants("file")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("name"), y => new File() { code = (string)y.Element("name"), name = (string)y.Element("name"), pagecount = (string)y.Element("pagecount") })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }
    }
    public class File
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string pagecount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I am new to C# could you help me in this logic? Dictionary comparison sounds good, what I will be doing now is finding the key in the `list<ZipArchiveEntry> afpfiles`, if it doesn't find the key then write it on console else continue comparing the Dictionary values by reading AFP file.

Comment: List<File> results = dict[key]; where key is the string you are searching for.